# #pragma unmanaged makes vc_redist a must dependency

Tags: visual-c++, dll, unmanaged, msix

My MSIX-packaged project uses a hand-made C++ DLL, which requires Visual C++ Runtime (vc_redist) to run, otherwise it will silently crash. I would like to allow users to run it without having to find / install vc_redist by themselves.

I did find people mentioning that including VCLibs as a dependency in the MSIX package manifest thing, but it didn't work for my project for some reason. I assume in some part of the code it is explicitly targeting the runtime from vc_redist.

Here is the project: https://github.com/AkazaRenn/FruitLanguageSwitcher/
The DLL project is inside at here:
https://github.com/AkazaRenn/FruitLanguageSwitcher/tree/main/Core/LanguageSwitcher

I can be certain that this DLL project is the issue, with this part removed the project would start with no problems.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Update: Did a lot of tests and found it's related to the `#pragma unmanaged` piece I put on the DLL. Didn't think too much about it since it seemed to be working, but actually it has an impact. I've changed it into a more precise way and seems fine now. Would like any explanation on such behavior.

Comment: You used C++/CLI so always have a dependency on the C and C++ runtime libraries. 
 vc_redist is primarily for end-users, all that you have to do is deploy the runtime libraries to the .exe install directory.  Typically just vcruntime140.dll and msvcp140.dll, use the Debug > Windows > Modules debugger window to verify.

Comment: @HansPassant I did include `Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop` as a dependency of the package and thought it would suffice, however the program specifically asks for `vc_redist`, that confused me quite a bit. Do you know if there's a reason it's behaving in this way?